# Send data to json file using jquery/ajax and php

Tags: php, json, ajax

I'm having some trouble writing to a JSON file using ajax/jQuery along with PHP. 
The code I have currently is:

**jQuery**

```
 var object = {
    name: 'John',
    occupation: 'Lawyer'
}

$(".testing-php").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {params:object},
        url: 'details.php',
        success: function (data) {
        console.log(object);
        alert('success');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

This part seems to be working correctly as the console.log statement correctly displays - {"name":"John","occupation":"Lawyer"}

My PHP file is currently like this:

```
      <?php
var_dump($_POST);
if (isset($_POST['params']) && strlen($_POST['params'])) {
    $params = $_POST['params'];
    $jsonObject = json_encode($params);
    if (is_writable('js/details.json')) {
        file_put_contents('js/details.json', $jsonObject);
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "file is not writable, check permissions";
    }
} else {
    echo "invalid params";
}
?>
```

Finally, the current JSON file looks like this:

```
{
"name": "Neil",
"occupation": "web developer"
}
```

**Update**

This is the information which the var_dump($_POST) displays.  Along with the message .invalid params'.

```
array(1) {
  ["params"]=>
  array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
string(4) "John"
["occupation"]=>
string(6) "Lawyer"
}
}
invalid params
```

The AJAX request parameters are on two different rows and are displayed as

params[name]:"John"

params[occupation]:"Lawyer"

I am simply hardcoding values at the moment until I get the process working. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here as the JSON file isn't being written to?

Many thanks

Comment: definitely something wrong, John the Lawyer is being written to file as Neil the Web Developer.... :-)

Comment: that's just some json that i put in the file to be replaced by the new json being written to it

Comment: i know, just kidding. Try adding `processData: false,` under `data: params,`

Comment: no luck yet thanks. it seems to be posting fine to the php file but there seems to be some error at that point

Comment: in the php just var_dump($_POST); and see what comes up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One extra `!` in this test got you the exact opposite of what you meant to do (read it as "not"), removing it should help. Also added/changed some tests.

It's also good practice to output something in your ajax query, so you can get some feedback from the server in your browser dev tools.

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);

if (isset($_POST['params'])) {
    $params = $_POST['params'];
    $jsonObject = json_encode($params);
    if (is_writable('js/details.json')) {
        file_put_contents('js/details.json', $jsonObject);
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "file is not writable, check permissions";
    }
} else {
    echo "invalid params";
}
```

---

**UPDATE** : Also updated your jQuery code to pass the params variable under a `params` key, for it to be picked up correctly server-side (no need to stringify as json by the way, jQuery does it on your behalf):

```
    var object = {
        name: 'John',
        occupation: 'Lawyer'
    }

    $(".testing-php").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {params:object},
            url: 'details.php',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(params);
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
```

---

**UPDATE** : Also removed a test to accomodate an array-typed `$_POST['params']`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that had fixed the issue but it still doesn't work unfortunately..

Comment: updated my answer, please give it a try and see what happens. I can't promise you everything is fixed, but at least we might know what goes wrong.

Comment: still isn't working.  Where can I see which echo statement is being executed to I can tell at which point the error takes place?
Currently I'm just clicking the button on the html page which produces the alert 'success' and then checking the json file to see if it has been updated.

Comment: In your browser, more tools/dev tools in chrome, firebug console/http in firefox. These are must haves for ajax development.

Comment: I see the response now. it says 'invalid params'

Comment: updated the answer, the `$_POST['params']` key was missing from the jQuery ajax call, and so couldn't be found server-side.

Comment: It still isn't working unfortunately! I really appreciate you taking the time to try to help

Comment: yw, time to look around in your dev tools now : can you inspect the ajax _request_ parameters ? can you add a `var_dump($_POST);` at the beginning of the php file and paste the output ? You might want to update the question with those and the updated code in its present state altogether.

Comment: Ok I've updated the first post with that information.  I also updated the console.log statement in the jquery to console.log(object) which returns I think correctly as: Object {name: "John", occupation: "Lawyer"}

Comment: Thanks for that. Updated my answer acordingly, should be ok now :)

Comment: Perfect now! Thank you very much.  Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to do some validation to make sure your params got there safely.